# Как изменить выведенный текст в консоли?

Tags: ruby, консоль

ради эксперимента захотел сделать следующее: в консоли выводить текст, а через некоторый промежуток времени заменить определённые слова в этом тексте на другие.

думал, сделать это на каком-нибудь sh или на ruby; выбрал ruby. как я понял, он в такое умеет, потому что есть как минимум brew. кстати, ruby я не знаю, поэтому был интерес выбрать его и чуть ознакомиться с языком.

вот такой простой код вывода в консоль у меня есть сейчас

```
first = "\n\e[1mSome bold text\n\n"
text = first + "\e[0mSome regural text\n"

print text
```

итак, как изменить уже выведенный/напечатанный текст в консоли/терминале с помощью ruby? например, такой эффект был в игре super hot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось, единственное решение — clear: system 'clear'

я очищаю экран и сразу вывожу отредактированный текст. всё получилось :)